# Constraint equation for an elastic pendulum

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, spring, string, constrained-dynamics

I would like to know if you can help me determine the restraining force for an elastic pendulum. The problem is the following

> A particle of mass $m$ is suspended by a massless spring of length $L$. It hangs, without initial motion, in a gravitational field of strength $g$. It is struck by an impulsive horizontal blow, which introduces an angular velocity $\omega$. If $\omega$ is sufficiently small, it is obvious that the mass moves as a simple pendulum. If $\omega$ is sufficiently large, the mass will rotate about the support. Use a Lagrange multiplier to determine the conditions under which the string becomes slack at some point in the motion

Since it asks me to solve by Lagrange multipliers I need the constraint force. My attempts were the following:

Since the mass is suspended from a spring, when it hits the spring, an angle theta will be formed and the spring will deform a length $z$. So in polar coordinates I could write $r=L+z$, however I'm not sure about this.

Another constraint I can use would be $\dot\theta=\omega$ since there will be angular velocity at the moment the pendulum is struck.

However, since you ask me for conditions for $L$, I believe that there should be no constraint force $Q_\theta$ and therefore, there should only be constraint force $Q_r$, this means then that my multiplier should only depend on $r$ and It makes me think my first attempt is the right one but I'm not sure. I hope you can help me, I will appreciate it. I only want the constraint equation, I can solve the rest.

Comment: Comment to the post (v3): Is the spring constant $k=\infty$? In other words, is the _spring_ an inextensible _string?_

Comment: Could you add a picture? From the description above in quoted lines, I'm imaging a simple pendulum with a spring instead of an inextensible wire. What follows in your question makes no sense to me: the mass doesn't hit anything

Comment: @basics I do not have a picture.  It's just the problem.  In fact it is problem 2.26 of classical mechanics from Goldstein third edition

Comment: @Qmechanic Don't know. That's all the information I have. They didn't give me any more information about the spring. I don't understand why first he talks about spring and at the end he mentions rope. It is problem 2.26 of the Goldstein third edition.

Comment: @Kale_1729 you find my solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The elastic pendulum have two generalized coordinate
$~x,y~$

from here the constraint equation

$$\tan(\theta)=\frac xy\quad,\omega\,t=\arctan(x/y)$$

and with $~x=r\,\sin(\theta),y=r\,\cos(\theta)$

you obtain two degrees of freedom $~r~,\theta~$ and  one constraint equation $~\omega\,t-\theta=0~$

---

with
$$U=-k\frac 12\,{r}^{2}+k\,L\,r-m\,g\,r\cos \left( \theta \right)$$

$$T= \frac 12\,m \left(  \left( \sin \left( \theta \right) {\dot r}+r\cos
 \left( \theta \right) \dot\theta  \right) ^{2}+ \left( \cos \left( 
\theta \right) {\dot r}-r\sin \left( \theta \right) \dot\theta  \right) ^
{2} \right) +\lambda\, \left( \omega\,t-\theta \right) 
$$

where L is the pendulum initial length , and $~\lambda~$ the Lagrange multiplier

you can obtain the equations of motions and the constraint force

Answer (score 0):

If you need to evaluate the reaction at the constraint with a Lagrangian approach, you need to add the constraint in the computation of the stationary point of the action.

Let's call $P$ the mass point, and $Q$ the point at the other extreme of the spring.

The constraint in $Q$ may be written as
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
x_Q = 0 \\
y_Q = 0 \ ,
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
while the "extended action" is written as
\begin{equation}
  S = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \left[ \mathscr{L}(\dot{q},q,t) - \lambda_x x_Q - \lambda_y y_Q \right] dt \ ,
\end{equation}
with the generalized coordinates $q$ that need to include the (constrained) coordinates of Q and other two coordinates to describe the position of $P$: as an example, I'd choose $r$, $\theta$ with $r$ the distance from $Q$ and $\theta$ the angle with the vertical line drawn from $Q$.

Then you need to evaluate the Lagrangian function $\mathscr{L}$ as a function of all the 4 generalized coordinates, and the 4 Lagrange equations resulting from the condition of the action functional to be stationary, $\delta S = 0$.

The Lagrangian function equals the sum of the kinetic energy $T$ and the potential $U$. The expression of these two functions are:

- kinetic energy
  \begin{equation}
  T = \dfrac{1}{2} m \left[ \dot{x}_Q^2 + \dot{y}_Q^2 + \dot{r}^2 + r^2 \dot{\theta}^2 + 2 \dot{x}_Q \dfrac{d}{dt} \left( r \sin \theta \right) - 2 \dot{y}_Q \dfrac{d}{dt} \left( r \cos \theta \right) \right]
  \end{equation}
- potential
  \begin{equation}
  U = \dfrac{1}{2} k r^2 + m g ( r \cos \theta - y_Q )
  \end{equation}

The Lagrangian functions w.r.t. $x_Q$ and $y_Q$ reads
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\lambda_x & = m \left( \ddot{r} \sin \theta + 2 \dot{r} \dot{\theta} \cos \theta + r \ddot{\theta} \cos \theta - r \dot\theta^2 \sin \theta \right) \\
\lambda_y & = m \left( - \ddot{r} \cos \theta + 2 \dot{r} \dot{\theta} \sin \theta + r \ddot{\theta} \sin \theta + r \dot\theta^2 \cos \theta  + g \right)
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

These are the components of the reaction at the constraint along $x$-axis (horizontal) and $y$-axis (vertical). Projecting along the radial and azimuthal direction, you get

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
 \lambda_{\theta} & = \lambda_x \cos \theta + \lambda_y \sin \theta = 0 \\
 \lambda_{r} & = - \lambda_x \sin \theta + \lambda_y \cos \theta = m (\ddot{r} - r \dot\theta^2 - g \cos \theta ) \ .
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
You can easily check these results:

- the azimuthal component of the force at the constraint must equal zero, for the equilibrium of the massless spring
- the radial component is the sum of the contribution of the acceleration of the mass in radial direction and the radial component of the gravity.